# Non-Mandatory Location Field on Cash Sales in NetSuite

Tags: netsuite

I am trying to disable the Location field so that it is not mandatory in NetSuite for Cash Sales.  I customed the form and unchecked the Mandatory box and it still shows up.  When I did this for Sales Orders I also had to update the Accounting Preferences to not require a Location.

Is it possible to perform what I am asking?  Do I simply need to disable locations site wide (as opposed to making them non-mandatory on the cash sales form)?

Comment: Do you want to remove field from form or just make it non mandatory?

Comment: Just make it non mandatory.  I unchecked the mandatory option, but it still shows required (red asterisk) and prompts me to enter it.

Answer (score 1):

Actually Locations are required on some transactions if `Multi-location Inventory` feature is enabled.

Though, you can make location non-mandatory using `beforeLoad User event Script` and using the code in there `form.getField('location').setMandatory(false)`

But, if you do that, you will get an error as location is required in this case:

> Multi-location Inventory Error (MLI_LOCATION_REQUIRED): this
>   transaction or its items must have locations